# Periodogram of time series with multiple seasonal behaviors

Tags: time-series, periodogram

I have a time series of sampled for every 5 minutes for  20 years of some geological signal. I would like to generate a periodogram in order to analyze what seasonal behavior affects the signal.  At the moment what I am doing is :

```
x_time <-  as.Date(data$date)
x <- data$signal
spec_ob <-spectrum(x,log="no")
```

[image]

But, I am not sure how to interpret it - how to translate the frequency into time?

Comment: the frequency of a signal (component) is the inverse of the time of a period of that signal (component).

Comment: @MarcusMüller How do I calculate it ?

Comment: the inverse of x is 1/x

Comment: @MarcusMüller So to get the period for days i should do (1/spec_ob$freq)*12*24 ? (since its sample every 5 min  -> (5 *12) * (24) = 60 * 24 = 1440 ?

Comment: I really don't "speak" the programming language you're using, but your horizontal axis is relative frequency – that means, frequency normalized to sampling frequency. So, the period you get when inverting that frequency is normalized to sample periods. For example, if your relative frequency is 0.01, then your normalized period is 100, i.e. 500 minutes.